# Function Pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

How can I create a "function pointer" (and (for example) the function has parameters) in C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

```
typedef int (*MathFunc)(int, int);

int Add (int a, int b) {
    printf ("Add %d %d\n", a, b);
    return a + b; }

int Subtract (int a, int b) {
    printf ("Subtract %d %d\n", a, b);
    return a - b; }

int Perform (int a, int b, MathFunc f) {
    return f (a, b); }

int main() {
    printf ("(10 + 2) - 6 = %d\n",
            Perform (Perform(10, 2, Add), 6, Subtract));
    return 0; }
```

Comment: Interesting example - *adding* a float and two chars?

Comment: Of course, haven't you always wanted to add 3.145 to 'z' and return the result as an integer!? I'll change the example to something a bit saner.

Answer (score 5):

```
    typedef int (*funcptr)(int a, float b);

    funcptr x = some_func;

    int a = 3;
    float b = 4.3;
    x(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this site helpful when I was first diving into function pointers.

http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

Answer (score 0):

First declare a function pointer:

```
typedef int (*Pfunct)(int x, int y);
```

Almost the same as a function prototype.
But now all you've created is a type of function pointer (with `typedef`).
So now you create a function pointer of that type:

```
Pfunct myFunction;
Pfunct myFunction2;
```

Now assign function addresses to those, and you can use them like they're functions:

```
int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

int subtract(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}

. . .

myFunction = add;
myFunction2 = subtract;

. . .

int a = 4;
int b = 6;

printf("%d\n", myFunction(a, myFunction2(b, a)));
```

Function pointers are great fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define functions that return pointers to functions:

```
int (*f(int x))(double y);
```

f is a function that takes a single int parameter and returns a pointer to a function that takes a double parameter and returns int.