# calling function by its address by another function in c

Tags: c, return, buffer, overflow

My goal for my program is to rewrite the return address to be return to another function `b()`.
I could reach and rewrite the return address but i couldn't get the address for function which i want to return to `b()`.

```
int main(){
  a();
}   

int a(){
  int *ret;
  ret=(int*)&ret+2;
  (*ret)=(int)b();  // <<<<<<<< Here is the problem !!!!
}

int b(){
}
```

Comment: What is your goal by doing such weird thing ?

Comment: This previous question is a good starting point for using function pointers in C - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278841/function-pointer-in-c

Comment: Any way you skin this cat will result in undefined behaviour, since there is no such thing as "the return address" in the C language standard.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `b()`, you're calling the `b` function. If you want the address of that function, just write `b`.

```
*ret=(int)b;
```

Note that I have no idea if that will do what you want, and it's not proper C - what you're trying to do is not possible in standard, portable C. It depends entirely on your implementation, CPU, and how the compiler will optimize all that code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set function a() to return a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I think its depend on your compiler, however you should try

int a(){
  int *ret;
  *(&ret+2)=b; 
}

but with different architectures the return address maybe store in a register that you cannot change it by this way.