# How to define a variable that is a function pointer that can assign other functions in c?

Tags: c

So if I was given a the following 2 functions:

```
void printhex(int x, char y, char z)
{
    printf("%x%x%x,x,y,z);
}
void printdecimal( int x, char y ,char z)
{
    printf("%i%i%i,x,y,z);
}
```

How would i define a variable, that is a function pointer, that can be assigned either of the 2 given functions?

Also within the main function how would i determine if any command line arguments were entered after the program name when the program was executed. If anything was entered, how would I be able to assign the function pointer to the function printhex, but otherwise would assign the function to printdecimal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function Pointer in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278841/function-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1) This is how the function pointer will look like:

```
void (*myFuncPtr)(int, char, char);
```

You then assign a function to it like this:

```
myFuncPtr = &printhex;
```

And call it like this:

```
(*myFuncPtr )(1, 'a', 'b');
```

A2) The `argc` variable of the `main()` will tell if any command line arguments were entered other than the program name itself. If `argc > 1`, then `argc - 1` other strings were passed when calling the program. This is because `argc` also counts the program name as one of the parameters. So something like this should work for you:

```
if (1 < argc)
{
    myFuncPtr = &printhex;
}
else
{
    myFuncPtr = &printdecimal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could declare a variable similarly to:

```
void (*printSomething)(int, char, char);
```

You could assign it to one of those functions with:

```
printSomething = &printhex;
```

or

```
printSomething = &printdecimal;
```

The & is completely optional, so you could also just write `printSomething = printhex;` for example.

You also didn't ask, but you can call the function through the pointer with (for example):

```
(*printSomething)(1, 2, 3);
```

The * is also optional, so you could just write:

```
printSomething(1, 2, 3);
```

If you need help with command line arguments as well, that should be a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a typedef

```
void printhex(int x, char y, char z) {
      printf("%x%x%x",x,y,z);
}

void printdecimal( int x, char y ,char z) {
      printf("%i%i%i",x,y,z);
}     

typedef void (*printer)(int x, char y ,char z);

printer hex = &printhex;
printer dec = &printdecimal;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, it should be simple:

```
void (* ptr)(int, char, char);
ptr = printhex;

(*ptr)(a, b, c); //this will call the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Such variable would be declared as

```
void (*fptr)(int, char, char);
```

then assigned a value:

```
fptr = printhex;
```

and used to invoke a function:

```
fptr(13, 'a', 'b');
```

Or you may declare a new name for the function type:

```
typedef void (*PrintFuncPtr)(int, char, char);
```

then use it for a variable declaration:

```
PrintFuncPtr  fptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a function pointer you would use the following syntax:

`return-type (*pointer name)(parameters);`

in this case, you would use:
`void (*fp)(int, char, char);` for a function pointer named `fp` suitable for the two functions you've defined.

Assigning a function pointer can be done like any other pointer, except you use the name of the function.  For example, `fp = printhex;` would do exactly what it says: assigning the address of `printhex` to the pointer `fp`.  You don't need to use the `&` operator for `printhex` because the identifier is implicitly converted to pointer-to-function.